# problem with threads in the while loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

what is problem in the my code?

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        int i = 0;
        ParameterizedThreadStart start = new
        ParameterizedThreadStart (gh);

        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;

        Thread u = new Thread(start);
        u.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

        while (i < 100)
        {
            if (u.IsBackground)
            {
                while (u.IsBackground)
                {
                    if (!u.IsBackground) break;
                }
            }
                u = new Thread(start);

                i++;
                u.Start(i);

           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }


    void gh(object e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            b = delegate()
            {
                label1.Text = string.Format("Step is :{0}", e.ToString());      
            };
            Invoke(b);
        }
        else label1.Text = string.Format("Step is :{0}", e.ToString());     
    }
```

}

Comment: Add description of what isn't working!

Comment: And what exactly you are trying to achieve with this code :)

Comment: And now we ask *you*: What is the problem in the code? It works for me, but I'm probably not expecting it to do the same thing you're expecting. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for tips on how to ask better questions.

Comment: Why would you check IsBackground?

Comment: Way to go with using readable names! (If someone handed me this code, I'd kick them in the eye)

Comment: First of all, it won't compile until you declare the type of `b` (`System.Action` will do the trick).

Comment: You are checking "while (u.IsBackground)" and breaking if u is not background? Makes no sense at all because the while does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide some more info on what's going wrong, or not doing what you expect. You would benefit from tidying up the code a little and adding comments. Some of it doesn't really make sense. Eg.:

```
if (u.IsBackground) {
    while (u.IsBackground)
    {
        if (!u.IsBackground)
            break;
    }
}
```

All of this code is doing the same thing - eating CPU while waiting for u.IsBackground to become false. This entire block is just like doing:

```
while (u.IsBackground) { }
```

However, it's bad practice to create loops like this, as they'll just eat up resources constantly evaluating. You should at least add a pause to significantly reduce the resources, used, eg.:

```
// Wait until the thread is no longer running in the background
while (u.IsBackground)
{
    // Sleep for 50 milliseconds before checking again, to avoid eating CPU.
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```